# Me da error de java al invocar función de Oracle como SP "cannot find symbol"

Tags: genexus

Agradezco cualquier ayuda para solucionar este tema
Tengo una serie de funciones creadas en una BD Oracle en la sección Packages con el nombre INTERFACE.XXXXX y subsección Functions

> En Genexus Evo3 U10 Java 1.6 Tomcat 6.0
>
> EO= External Object

1)  Creé un EO  de tipo Stored Procedure con un nombre  NombreEO y con métodos con cada una de las funciones, llamémoslas f_metodo1, f_metodo2, … cada una con sus parámetros de in. Como Gx maneja las funciones como SP con un solo parámetro out de retorno, le agregué ese parámetro out 
El EO referencia al data store de Oracle

2)  En el Data Store de la BD Oracle, en List of external stored procedures puse los métodos f_metodo1 f_metodo2 … y en el Database schema puse INTERFACE.XXXXX el nombre del package que contiene las funciones

3)  En el procedure actualiza_XXXXX que usa los métodos, creé una variable

&NombreEO de tipo NombreEO y en el código invoqué

```
&NombreEO.f_metodo1(&paramIN1, … &paramOUT)
```

….

La especificación de genexus es exitosa
La generación es exitosa

pero la compilación Java da el error

> GeneXus Java Make v1.0 com\ahev3\actualiza_XXXXX.java:86: cannot find
>   symbol symbol  : class f_metodo1 location: package com.ahev3
>            new com.ahev3.f_metodo1(remoteHandle, context).execute( GXv_char1, GXv_int2) ;

Mi pregunta es

Porqué no crea los símbolos correspondientes?

Falta declarar algo más?

Está bien poner en el Database schema el nombre del package?

Answer (score 0):

El problema se puede deber a diferentes factores, primero revisa cómo estás mandando los parámetros al EO ya que solo le debes mandar variables de un tipo sencillo, por ejemplo no mandes la variable de un sdt , ni atributos.

Si lo anterior no funciona, en mi caso para llamar a una función de un package en la base de datos creo un store procedure que sirve como puente y lo único que hace es llamar a una función del package. Ya que según se desde genexus no puedes llamar directamente a un package.

Comment: 1) Estoy enviando variables escalares como varchar y esperando un retorno numeric. Cumpliendo además con que sea un solo out parameter ya que especifican que las funciones no están soportadas salvo que se las utilice como SP con una variable de retorno

2) La BD es de un proveedor externo y solamente puedo usar las funciones que proveen. De no encontrar otra solución, debería encargar su desarrollo al mismo

Answer (score 0):

1) Efectivamente tenía un error de interpretación y lo que la especificación indica y lo que aportó Jesús Rodríguez Barrera me indicaron que no debe usarse un sdt de ninguna manera como parámetro, no sólo la forma &sdt, con la estructura entera, sino tampoco como uno de sus elementos, p. ej. &sdt.a. En lugar de éste, habría que hacer algo como &a= &sdt.a y pasarle &a como parámetro. Obviamente siendo además &a de un tipo simple como varchar, numeric, etc.

2) Un segundo problema que descubrí en esta particular versión de Genexus Evo 3 U10 es que cuando definí los métodos en el EO, si p. ej. el método tiene los 3 parámetros a, b, c y por error los incluí en el orden b, a, c, el corregirlo por desplazamiento del parámetro al 1er lugar, dejaba las cosas internamente como a, b, a, c. La manera de salvar este inconveniente fue borrar el método y reescribirlo bien de una sola vez

Con esto el problema del error de compilación de Java quedó resuelto